# How to download data from multiple CSV files with dynamic URL which change based on date?

Tags: python

I need to download data from multiple CSV files having URL with standard structure -

'https://archives.nseindia.com/products/content/sec_bhavdata_full_ddmmyyyy.csv'

*ddmmyyyy = variable representing date*

I am trying to loop through the dates after passing them as strings. But, I get out of memory error or it's taking too long to download data for more than 50 dates.
Final requirement is to combine and store data as CSV (with rows and column aligned and without any gaps).
Code -

```
strings = ['31122020','30122020','29122020','28122020','24122020','23122020','22122020']
result = []
import pandas as pd

for x in strings:  
    result.append(pd.read_csv('https://archives.nseindia.com/products/content/sec_bhavdata_full_'+x+'.csv',index_col=0))

big_df = pd.concat(result)
big_df.to_csv('C:/combined.csv')
```

Is there a way to download this data in a faster way without errors for more number of dates in python?

Comment: With just the 7 dates you've provided, `big_df` has over 140k rows. For 50 dates, this would get *really* large. Consider working on smaller "chunks" of the DataFrame at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try writing each "chunk" to file as you read it:

```
import pandas as pd

dates = ['31122020','30122020','29122020','28122020','24122020','23122020','22122020']

for i, dt in enumerate(dates):
    chunk = pd.read_csv(f"https://archives.nseindia.com/products/content/sec_bhavdata_full_{dt}.csv", index_col=0)
    if i==0:
        chunk.to_csv("C:/combined.csv", header=True)
    else:
        chunk.to_csv("C:/combined.csv", header=False, mode="a")
```